# Autofac - how to configure ResolutionPipeline on a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac

I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1 / Autofac 6, and would like to configure a resolution pipeline middleware on a controller.

This is how I do it on a class I'm the owner of:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyService>().As<IMyService>().ConfigurePipeline(p => { /* */ });
```

However, when I do it on a controller, it doesn't work:

```
builder.RegisterType<WeatherForecastController>().AsSelf().ConfigurePipeline(...);
```

I know that the reason might be that I already have:

```
services.AddControllers();
```

but I'm not sure what to do about it. Any ideas?

Comment: And what you will be accomplished by doing that?

Comment: I want to have my resolution logic for controllers - let's try not to go away from topic pls., let's just say I have a reason.

Comment: Have you already followed our documentation on resolving Controllers from DI (not the default in ASP.NET Core)? https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#controllers-as-services

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Alistair Evans, that's it. The [referenced docs](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#controllers-as-services) are mentioning `.AddMvc()`, but for the API it would be:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddControllers().AddControllersAsServices();
}
```

Then in container registration:

```cs
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    //...
    builder.RegisterType<WeatherForecastController>().ConfigurePipeline(p =>
       {
         /* ... */
       }
}
```